# How to get a package name from Absolute Path?

Tags: java, path, classpath

I have the following String example which contains Absolute Path for a class

`String myPath = "C:\Users\com\module\mypackage\MyClass.class"`
Need to get The package name:
 `"com.module.mypackage"`
Is there any Build in library for That?

Comment: try https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-get-package-name-of-a-class/

Comment: First,deserialize the class;Second,get the Class Object clz;Third,call method `class.clz.getPackage().getName()`

Comment: @TongChen Thanks for your reply
How to deserialize  from a String to class ? in case of 
`myPath .getClass().getPackage()`  i will get java.lang.String package

Comment: @JRobes Thanks for your reply
But in your case , you have initialized a new instance of the class ... 
In my case i got a relative path as String input , and need to convert it to a Java Object

Comment: @khilo   I am so sorry,I misunderstood your question before. A .class file can't deserialize class object,so the method I provided is wrong.I have some ideas，1 read the file and get the package info. 2 I try to make a URLClassLoader(myPath) and use loadClass(String) to the load the class,but throw one NoClassDefFoundError execption,the exception info contains the package info,but it's a good way to get package info.I will do try to resolve this.

Comment: I would read the binary class file to look for such info. See Class File Format at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html